# How to clear state in react upon `onKeyDown` on an input form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, material-ui

I have an input component in React where input is submitted by pressing Enter key. I'm using [material-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) components as the basis for my component. Inside `onKeyDown` even handler I clear state by assigning empty string to the only field in the component's state. However this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getAppInfo } from '../../actions/appActions.js';

const styles = theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
    width: '100%',
  }
})

class AppSearchBarInput extends Component {
  state = {
    appId: ''
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ appId: e.target.value });
  }

  onKeyDown = e => {

    const { appId } = this.state;

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.props.getAppInfo({ appId });
      this.setState({
        appId: ''
      });
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <InputBase
        placeholder="Search…"
        classes={{
          root: classes.inputRoot,
          input: classes.inputInput,
        }}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
      />
    )
  }
}

const AppSearchBarWithStyles = withStyles(styles)(AppSearchBarInput);
const AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter = withRouter(AppSearchBarWithStyles);
export default connect(null, { getAppInfo })(AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Input's value otherwise it doesn't know what variable to display and uses it's own, which doesn't clear.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getAppInfo } from '../../actions/appActions.js';

const styles = theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    color: 'inherit',
    width: '100%',
  }
})

class AppSearchBarInput extends Component {
  state = {
    appId: ''
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ appId: e.target.value });
  }

  onKeyDown = e => {

    const { appId } = this.state;

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.props.getAppInfo({ appId });
      this.setState({
        appId: ''
      });
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <InputBase
        placeholder="Search…"
        classes={{
          root: classes.inputRoot,
          input: classes.inputInput,
        }}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
        value={this.state.appId}
      />
    )
  }
}

const AppSearchBarWithStyles = withStyles(styles)(AppSearchBarInput);
const AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter = withRouter(AppSearchBarWithStyles);
export default connect(null, { getAppInfo })(AppSearchBarWithStylesWithRouter);
```

Comment: this worked. Is this because I use material-ui package for the component or is it a React thing? How is the `value` prop connected to the state of `AppSearchBarInput `?

Comment: @hitchhiker it's a react thing. since that worked would you click the check to mark this as the answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the solution? I'd like to understand what was the reason for the error, not just fix it.

Comment: @hitchhiker it wasn't an error per say, input tags provide a `value` attribute that are meant primarily to set a default value, but with react, it allows you to manage state for the input since normally they provide their own. React has some pretty good documentation on it here https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html